# How many ways to arrange 10 people between a group of size 4 and a group of size 6?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations

I was trying to understand the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893671/how-many-different-ways-can-2-groups-of-10-be-divided-into-10-groups-of-2) which was very similar but I couldn't understand it well. Based on the answer in the link I'm thinking it would be

(10 nPr 4) * (6 nPr 6) = 3628800 different arrangements

I wouldn't be dividing between 2! since the groups are not of equal sizes and does not need to consider the reordering. Is this correct? I'm also not sure whether it would need to be solved with permutations or combinations.

Comment: There are $\binom{10}4$ ways to choose a group of $4$ people from a pool of $10$. Once you’ve done that, the remaining $6$ people automatically form the group of $6$. Thus, there are just $\binom{10}4=210$ ways to split the pool of $10$ into a group of $4$ and a group of $6$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @regeant: I’m afraid that I don’t understand your question. What do you mean by ‘tall-short patterns’? (It’s 04:00 here, so I probably won’t be around to respond again for several hours.)

Answer (score 1):

Since orders do not matter within each group, you should be using combinations rather than permutations

so you could have written $\,^{10}C_4 \,^6C_6$ or ${10 \choose 4}{6\choose 6}$, which as Brian M. Scott says in a comment is $210$

This differs from your answer by a factor of $4!\times 6!$.

To see this with a smaller example, if you were splitting three people into a group of two and a group of one, would you say $3$ possibilities or $6$?